# DataFrames.jl Number of rows

Tags: dataframe, julia

I'd like to get the number of rows of a dataframe.
I can achieve that with `size(myDataFrame)[1]`.
Is there a cleaner way ?

Comment: you can use `size(myDataFrame, 1)` to see the size across the 1st dimension.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you are using `DataFrames` specifically, then you can use `nrow()`:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(Any[1:10, 1:10]);
julia> nrow(df)
10
```

Alternatively, you can specify the dimension argument for `size`:

```
julia> size(df, 1)
10
```

This also work for arrays as well so it's a bit more general:

```
julia> my_array = rand(4, 3)
4×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.980798  0.873643  0.819478
 0.341972  0.34974   0.160342
 0.262292  0.387406  0.00741398
 0.512669  0.81579   0.329353

julia> size(my_array, 1)
4
```